# Wondering what the phrase 'spore inventory' really mean in the context

Tags: word-meaning

“We’ve succeeded in maintaining the bear population well over the past few years. The results we’ve had from the spore inventory in 2009 shows that we are keeping the population at roughly the same level since 2004,” explains Björn Jonsson, head of conservation in the area, to the paper.

From http://m.thelocal.se//20120820/42724

My try is that : The word inventory has to do with a list of all bears in the country but I do not know why the guy used the word 'spore'  here. It could not have anything to do with the cell like seed from some plants. They are talking about bears. Very confusing.

Comment: My guess is that it's just a typo.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo or misspelling.

Comment: This is from a Swedish source, and it could be an error either in hearing or in translation: Swedish *spor*, "spore", is very similar in pronunciation to *spår*, "track".

Comment: @FumbleFingers If it is a typo and the original poster does not know it's a typo, than I don't see how that can make it off-topic. If someone must know the correct answer to a question before they are allowed to post, there's little point in posting.

Comment: @Jay: Perhaps we have different ideas about the *purpose* of this site. To my mind, if a question is asked which has little chance of being relevant to any *future* visitor with the same or similar question, it's Off Topic. No-one else is ever likely to come here looking for enlightenment because of a "similar" typo. Common courtesy dictates that the user should be given an answer if that's reasonably practical. So I would have provided the relevant "correct word" ***in my closevote comment*** if someone hadn't already posted an answer anyway. I don't see the point of *voting* for such trivia.

Comment: It is **not** a typographical error or misspelling, it's confusion due to two homophones. Although it's not a common word, the question could be helpful in the future.

Comment: @relaxing: It seems inarguable to me that writing ***spore*** when you mean ***spoor*** is a spelling mistake. For what it's worth, Google Books has one single relevant instance of [**spore** inventory](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22spore+inventory%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) spelled correctly (in a sentence which happens to be ungrammatical for other reasons), and *no instances* of [**spoor** inventory](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22spoor+inventory%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), so I really can't see anyone else facing this otherwise General Reference problem.

Comment: Yes, but I don't think the author meant to write spoor -- instead, she heard and understood a different word. "Spoor inventory" isn't a multiword expression -- the phrase's meaning is readily apparent from the individual words. So the fact that that formation of "inventory of spoors" doesn't appear in literature is no cause for concern.  Finally, I don't see what's ungrammatical about the sentence. The multiple clauses at the end are somewhat awkward, but not wrong I think?

Answer (score 3):

'[Spoor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spoor_%28animal%29)' (animal tracks or scat) is correct word here. The journalist probably misheard, or mistranscribed.